# Docker and "The OpenSSL library reported an error" when deployed

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, openssl, rust, rusoto

I'm providing an API via Rust and Rocket via Amazon Elastic Container Service. Whenever I put or get objects to Amazon S3, it works great locally, but if deployed on Amazon ECS, I'm getting this run-time error:

```
HttpDispatch(HttpDispatchError { message: "The OpenSSL library reported an error" })
```

This also happens when I run the Docker image on my machine.

I've added comments where the error is happening:

```
use super::types::SomeCustomType;
use rusoto_core::{DefaultCredentialsProvider, Region, default_tls_client};
use rusoto_s3::{S3, S3Client, GetObjectRequest};

pub fn load_data_from_s3(object_name: String) -> SomeCustomType {
    let credentials = DefaultCredentialsProvider::new().unwrap();
    let client = S3Client::new(default_tls_client().unwrap(), credentials, Region::UsWest2);
    let mut request = GetObjectRequest::default();
    request.bucket = "bucket-name".to_string();
    request.key = object_name.to_string();
    match client.get_object(&request) {
        // *** This is going to fail in docker container on run-time ***
        Ok(file) => {
            // this part is actually not important for this example,
            // so code has been omitted
            someCustomType
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{:?}", e); // *** errors out here! ***
            SomeCustomType::default()
        }
    }
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
brotli="1.0.8"
chrono = "0.3.1"
fnv = "1.0.5"
rusted_cypher = "1.1.0"
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket", rev = "614297eb9bc8fa5d9c54f653dc35b8cc3a22891f" }
rocket_codegen = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket", rev = "614297eb9bc8fa5d9c54f653dc35b8cc3a22891f" }
rocket_contrib = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket", rev = "614297eb9bc8fa5d9c54f653dc35b8cc3a22891f" }
rusoto_core = "0.25.0"
rusoto_s3 = "0.25.0"
serde = "1.0.8"
serde_json = "1.0.2"
serde_derive = "1.0.8"
```

This is how I build the Docker image on macOS:

```
cargo clean &&
docker run -v $PWD:/volume -w /volume -t manonthemat/muslrust cargo build --release &&
docker build -t dockerimagename .
```

The Docker image *manonthemat/muslrust* is essentially *clux/muslrust*. I had to build my own image because I needed a more recent nightly build of Rust.

This is the (simplified) **Dockerfile** which has been working great for me so far:

```
FROM scratch
ADD target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/project /
CMD ["/project"]
```

---

Some of the things I've tried to resolve the issue....

1. Added `openssl = "0.9.14"` to the Cargo.toml.
2. Change my Dockerfile to this:

   ```
   FROM alpine:edge

   ADD target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/project /    
   RUN apk add --no-cache curl perl openssl-dev ca-certificates linux-headers build-base zsh

   CMD ["/project"]
   ```

   This also didn't change anything, but gave me some more options to look inside.
3. I changed the cross-compilation step after `cargo clean` to this:

   ```
   docker run -v $PWD:/volume -w /volume -e RUST_LOG="rusoto,hyper=debug" -e OPENSSL_STATIC=1 -e OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local -t manonthemat/muslrust cargo build --release --features "logging"
   ```

   After the new docker images was built, get a shell:

   ```
   docker run -i -e ROCKET_ENV=prod -e ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 -e RUST_LOG="rusoto,hyper=debug" dockerimagename /bin/zsh
   ```

   There I executed my project by providing a different path to the ssl certificates that doesn't exist with no different effect.

   In the next run, I set it to point to a different path:
   `SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs /project` and I got an interesting result, when printing out the error of the `client.get_object(&request)` call:

   ```
   Unknown("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>...
   ```
4. I replaced rusoto with the aws-sdk-rust crate

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error dispatching request: HttpDispatchError { message: "the handshake failed" }', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:860            stack backtrace:
    0: std::sys::imp::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace                                                                                                            at ./checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:49
    1: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print                                                                                                                                  at ./checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:71
    2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}                                                                                                                           at ./checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:60
              at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:355
    3: std::panicking::default_hook
              at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:371
    4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:549
    5: std::panicking::begin_panic
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:511
    6: std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:495
    7: rust_begin_unwind
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:471
    8: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at ./checkout/src/libcore/panicking.rs:69
    9: core::result::unwrap_failed
   10: <aws_sdk_rust::aws::s3::s3client::S3Client<P, D>>::get_object
   11: himitsu::ingest::load_data_from_s3
   12: himitsu::ingest::load_data
   13: himitsu::main
   14: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at ./checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98
   15: std::rt::lang_start
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:433
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/panic.rs:361
             at ./checkout/src/libstd/rt.rs:59
```

5. I installed a Linux distribution via VirtualBox on my Mac, updated libraries, installed the OpenSSL headers and rust, then imported the project. Now I'm getting the SignatureDoesNotMatch error right away. I verified that I can access a Neo4j server via https through the vpn of the host machine, so SSL seems to work at least in parts.
6. Compiling and running the project on Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.a works. Building the docker image works, too. Running the docker image from within that system does not, as it returns with `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` even though the file is there, has the right permissions, can run other operations on it etc... Just not executing it. This is also the case when rolling back to a previous state that doesn't have any S3/OpenSSL dependencies. This is true for `scratch` and `alpine` base images. But, if I build the docker image with `ubuntu` as base image, I get the pre-S3/OpenSSL version running. For the version with rusuto, I'll get an OpenSSL error, even when installing the OpenSSL library and its headers.
7. Compiled the Docker image on my Mac, pushed to private repo to docker hub. Pulled that docker image via ssh session onto EC2 instance (same one as in 6). Running it now does not give me the "no such file or directory" error as in 6, but the good ol' `HttpDispatch(HttpDispatchError { message: "The OpenSSL library reported an error" })` (now even when passing SSL_CERTS_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs into the container's environment)

Comment: Plus one. A docker question with some code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps I've taken to make the deployment work on AWS.

I'm sure there are ways to optimize this and I will edit this post as I'll learn more about the process, but these are the steps I've taken.

1. I built the binary on macOS:

   `docker run -v $PWD:/volume -w /volume -e RUST_LOG="rusoto,hyper=debug" -e OPENSSL_STATIC=1 -e OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local -e SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs -t manonthemat/muslrust cargo build --release --features "logging"`
2. I modified the Dockerfile

   `FROM alpine:edge
   COPY target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/project /
   RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache pkgconfig openssl-dev ca-certificates linux-headers && update-ca-certificates
   CMD [ "/project" ]`
3. I built the docker image

   - *I then pushed the docker image to a private repo and pulled it via ssh-session on the EC2 instance for testing. I ran it successfully via `docker run -e SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs secretuser/secretrepo:notsosecrettag`*
4. I tagged and pushed the docker image to the AWS repository
5. For a successful run on Amazon Elastic Container Service, I had to modify the task definition. In the containerDefinitions I had to up the memory and add this into the environment array:

   ```
   `{
     "name": "SSL_CERT_DIR",
     "value": "/etc/ssl/certs"
   }`
   ```
6. For some unknown and probably unrelated reason I also had to update the agents on the EC2 instances and then restart those.

Answer (score 1):

try running

`update-ca-certificates` in the image

like:

```
FROM scratch
ADD target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/project /
RUN update-ca-certificates
CMD ["/project"]
```

Comment: At what step? For the original approach using `FROM scratch`, there's no place for that, as there's no `/bin/sh` that could even execute `update-ca-certificates`.  If plugged into let's say the docker image that's build from Alpine, then running `update-ca-certificates` still has nothing to do with the `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` error I'm getting.

Comment: you can always add the step before you run you script.

Comment: from scratch is for images you build yourself, to shrink layers, to debug you should use the origonal image

Comment: And what would that "original image" be if all I'm doing is compiling a binary? The original image is "scratch". Either you haven't read the whole post or you need to put a little bit more explanation into your answers, because I'm not sure what kind of good advice you want to give me here.

Comment: where is 'scratch' from? You built it or it's missing something. So you go from the original of the binary, or you make your own. What I'm suggesting is that you need to run `update-ca-certificates` before you run your script. Even with the binary you can add a `RUN update-ca-certificates` command. before your entrypoint. See edit

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#creating-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch

Comment: I know what a scratch image is. Your exe just doesn't have all the dependencies it needs to work with the openSSL library properly. So, either you compile everything statically, or you run the proper commands and install the dependencies before you run your exe.